# Queue, front and rear not declared in scope

Tags: c++, queue, declaration

I'm trying to create a Queue program, but I keep getting errors that "front" and "rear" are not declared in this scope.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Here is my code.  I've comparing it to other code I've written, and I've declared them exactly the same way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
  public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node();
};

class que{
  public:
    node *front;
    node *rear;
    void enq(int a);
    void deq();
    void pq();
    que();
};

que::que(){
  front = NULL;
  rear = NULL;
}


node::node(){
  data = 0;
  next = NULL;
}

void enq(int a){
  node *temp;
  temp = new node;
  temp->data = a;
  if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
    front = rear = temp;
  }
  else{
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
  }
}

void deq(){
  node *temp;
  temp = front;
  if(front == NULL)
    return;
  if(temp == rear)
    front = rear = NULL;
  else{
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  delete temp;
}

void pq(){
  node *curs;
  curs = front;
  if(front == NULL)
    return;
  while(1){
    cout << curs->data;
    if(curs->next == NULL)
      break;
    else
      curs=curs->next;
  }

}

int main(){

  que *Q = new que;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing `que::` in front of the methods definitions.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I can't believe I missed that, I've been staring at this for an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you start defining functions like:

```
void pq(){
```

But that's not part of the class, you have to say:

```
void deq::pq(){
```